# mongodb returns Cursor, I loop through and add objects into an array, how do I send the array to the client side without third party libraries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, es6-promise

this is what I have done so far:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/interview_prac', function(err, db) {
    var item = []
    if (err)
        throw err;
    else {
        var nettuts = db.collection('nettuts')
        var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            nettuts.find({gender: 'm'}, function(err, data) {
                if (err)
                    throw err
                if (data) {
                    data.forEach(function(myDoc) {
                        item.push(myDoc)
                    })
                }
            });
        });
        p1.then(
            res.render('index', {data: item})
        ).catch(function(reason) {
            console.log(reason)
        });
    }

 })
});
```

I want to send `item` to the client side, however, it get sends before `myDoc` are added into item. I am using promise, the page does render. However there is nothing in item. When I replace `data:item` with `data:'hello'`, the `hello` does appear on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node 6+ has Promises and the MongoDB 2.2 client returns native promises so you shouldn't require any third party libraries (although I would recommend [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com))

```
let db = null

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  let items = []
  mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nettuts')
  .then(db => {
    let nettuts = db.collection('nettuts')
    return nettuts.find({gender: 'm'}).toArray()
  })
  .then(data => {
    if (data) data.forEach(myDoc => items.push(myDoc));
    console.log(data)
    res.render('index', {data: items})
    db.close()
  })
  .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

A few notes

- Connecting, setting up your collection and disconnecting every request is not something you would do outside of testing
- The `items.push` is redundant in this, as you already have the `data` array, but again I assume your are testing things.

Comment: @Suji Did you miss the `let db = null` outside the get?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to call `res.render('index', {data: item});` using the `item` object instead of the `data` object.

Comment: yes, you are right, but it still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Try it without `db.close()`. Everything looks okay to me

Comment: Also you should check `data.length` to make sure it's iterable

Comment: Removing DB.close doesn't help. `data` is iterable. I checked it.

Comment: nope, I can't get it to work because javascript is asynchronous

Comment: okay when it sends, what does it send? Can you also log just before the `res.render()` to confirm, it gets there.

Comment: it send `[ ]`. Well it looks like I have to use Promise